# Python - AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to'

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I now have the updated code as follows:

```
    # Hyperparameters
random_seed = 123
learning_rate = 0.01
num_epochs = 10
batch_size = 128
```

device = torch.device("cuda:1" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
model = resnet34.train()
for batch_idx, (features, targets) in enumerate(train_generator):

```
    features = features.to(device)
    targets = targets.to(device)
        
    ### FORWARD AND BACK PROP
    logits = model(features)
    cost = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(logits, targets)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    cost.backward()
    
    ### UPDATE MODEL PARAMETERS
    optimizer.step()
    
    ### LOGGING
    if not batch_idx % 50:
        print ('Epoch: %03d/%03d | Batch %03d/%03d | Cost: %.4f' 
               %(epoch+1, num_epochs, batch_idx, 
                 len(datagen)//batch_size, cost))

model = model.eval() # eval mode to prevent upd. batchnorm params during inference
with torch.set_grad_enabled(False): # save memory during inference
    print('Epoch: %03d/%03d training accuracy: %.2f%%' % (
          epoch+1, num_epochs, 
          compute_accuracy(model, train_generator)))
```

When having only one image, the code runs fine. But, when I add another image or more, I get the following:

```
features = features.to(device)
targets = targets.to(device)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to'
```

Comment: Can you show how `train_generator` was defined?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: obviously it's a numpy array, not a pytorch tensor, but you think it's a pytorch tensor, because you call `.to(device)` on it, which is not possible with numpy arrays, because they aren't pytorch tensors. I hope that was clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be nice to see your `train_generator` code for clarity, but it does not seem to be a torch `DataLoader`. In this case, you should probably convert your arrays to tensors manually. There are several ways to do so:

- `torch.from_numpy(numpy_array)` - for numpy arrays;
- `torch.as_tensor(list)` - for common lists and tuples;
- `torch.tensor(array)` should also work but the above ways will avoid copying the data when possible.